# ASP.NET Page_Init Fired Twice!

Tags: asp.net

I have AutoEventWireup="true" and in my code behind

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}
```

When I'm debugging, the Page_Init method is getting fired twice!

Whats going on?

Comment: Please post the entire code-behind file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's make sure we cover the basics here:

Do you have any controls on your page that have server events?  If so, remember that *every* postback re-creates the *entire page.*  So, to handle an event means running *all* of the code required put the page together, including your Init and Load events.

> Always two there are, no more no less.  A request and a response.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have some sort of redirect or ajax postback that is firing.

Comment: I shouldn't even say this, as I hate nitpicking/rep-whoring, but if my answer was the correct one, you should probably mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any code anywhere that looks something like this?

```
this.Init += Page_Init;
```

If so you are accidentally wiring the event twice.  Either delete the manual event wiring or set `AutoEventWireup` to `false`.